# AWS Keys best practices

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

This may seem like a dumb question, but I have been looking everywhere and struggling to find an answer. I am working on a web application that uses AWS Cognito. So far, we have been handling sign up and sign in entirely through a node js server, using the AWS SDK downloaded via NPM. This has worked for us, but it has been a struggle since almost every available example uses the javascript SDK assuming you are loading the script through a client side web page, not a node.js server.

We want to try transitioning our application to use client side user sign up and log in, but are concerned about having our keys (user pool id, app client id, etc) in js files that a computer savvy individual could access just by inspecting their browser and un-minifying our code. Is there a reason to be concerned about a user accessing that information? If so, what is the best practice for keeping that information hidden in a client side web application? If not, why is this not a concern?

(NOTE: I will also be posting this question on the aws forums, and will share the answers here if I find anything!)